# mvc 4 template upgrade nuget packages

Tags: jquery-ui, nuget, asp.net-mvc-4

I installed the MVC 4 beta and created a new project. 
The standard template looks great now.

When you go to the nuget package manager, there are some packages that you could update.
When you update the all except Jquery UI the standard template works fine. When you also upgrade Jquery UI from 1.8.11 to 1.8.17, you get a script error on opening the default template template page.

Does someone know what is going on to solve this? I also changed the _references.js file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem: jQuery.UI.Combined Version 1.8.17 - switch to 1.8.16

Comment: So it is a JQuery problem. Do you know how to get an older version by nuget packages?

Comment: @LockTar: you should update to jQuery UI (Combined Library) 1.8.18 (released 3/7/2012) - It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Did you make sure to update your script references in the views/shared/_layout.cshtml page? You need to update that to the proper version of the jquery/jquery UI and it should work.

Comment: You don't have to change the script reference because the minifying functionality takes that over for you. This is done in the _references.js file

Comment: I'm not talking about the reference at the top of the file those are only used for inelisnese. I'm talking about the script tags on the pages aka < script src={something} >